# OpenXML - Protect all sheets

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml-sdk

I'm able to protect just one sheet, but when I try to protect all sheets in my Excel Documents I get an error while trying to append the SheetProtection.

If I've understood correctly, I must append SheetProtection after the SheetData.
Here is my code:

```
SheetProtectiond sheetProtection = 
  new SheetProtection                              
  {
    Sheet = true,
    Objects = true,
    Scenarios = true,
    Password = GetSheetPassword(workbookPassword)
  };

foreach(Sheet sheet in sheet)
{
  WorksheetPart worksheetPart = 
    GetWorksheetPartBySheetID(m_SpreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart, sheet.Id);
  worksheetPart.Worksheet.InsertAfter(sheetProtection, 
    worksheetPart.Worksheet.Descendants<SheetData>().LastOrDefault());                      
}
```

Comment: Its better to create an answer for your question instead of changing the question itself..

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by creating an instance of `SheetProtection` for each sheets.